# AOSP: enable adb over ethernet by default

Tags: adb, android-source, selinux

I am working on porting/configuring Android 9.0 for a custom device.

The device is based on the PICO-IMX8MM system-on-module by TechNexion.
The device does not have USB ports available to the end-user, only ethernet. In order to enable the end-user to develop Android applications on this device, I would like adb over ethernet to be enabled by default.

I have added the following to the `init.rc` script (which resides on the device at `/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.freescale.rc`):

```
on boot
    # Enable adb over ethernet
    setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
```

When I set SELinux to "permissive" mode, I can see (via `getprop | grep adb`) that the property is correctly set, and indeed the device is discoverable on the network (via `adb devices`).

However when I set SELinux to "enforcing" mode, the property is not set. I suspect that the vendor init script is not allowed to set the `service.adb.tcp.port` property.

The property context of the property is:

```
service.adb.tcp.port    u:object_r:shell_prop:s0
```

I don't know about SELinux configuration files, I only roughly understand the concepts.

How can I configure the SELinux policy to allow the vendor init script to set the property `service.adb.tcp.port` ?

Comment: Please check SELinux policy violation error message related to setting the property. Use this command to get error messages of all SEPolicy violations : `adb shell su root dmesg | grep 'avc: '`. Reference : [Validating SELinux > Reading denials](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate#reading_denials).

Comment: Great suggestion, I tried that already. I can't find any avc denial related to property setting. Probably these messages are lost due to `audit: audit_lost=10 audit_rate_limit=5 audit_backlog_limit=64` and `audit: rate limit exceeded`. Is there anything I can do to get the complete list of audit messages?